# Unix - Csh: How to load new shell with clear environment?

Tags: shell, unix, csh, tcsh

I have a **csh** shell that is "dirty" with a lot of modifications in `PATH`, in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and in more environment variables.

I want to load a "clean" **csh** shell that will not "inherit" all the environment settings from the existing one, but that will only source the `$HOME/.cshrc.USER` file.

How shall I do such thing?

Thanks!

Comment: I've just succeeded to do it using `ssh $HOST`. Does anyone have a suggestion for a more standard solution?

Comment: Read [csh considered harmful](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html) and switch to a better shell (e.g. [zsh](http://zsh.org/)...)

Comment: Thank you for this tip, but I work in a big company and can't change the way of work here :)

Comment: Did you read the documentation of your shell? You could start a non-interactive shell.

Comment: yes, could not find a solution there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally succeeded to do it by `ssh`ing to my `localhost`

```
> setenv DUMMY 123
> echo $DUMMY
123
> ssh localhost
> echo $DUMMY
DUMMY: Undefined variable
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the standard `env -i` to start any program with an empty environment.

Comment: How can I use it? Just run on the shell `env -i` and the environment gets cleaned?

Comment: I don't want it to be totally clear of environment variables. I.e., I want `/usr/bin` to be in `PATH` and I want `$HOME/.cshrc.$USER` to be sourced

Comment: @user3322273: Try: `env -i csh`. If it doesn't source your config file, then try `env -i HOME="$HOME" USER="$USER" csh` or source it manually.

Comment: I think I prefer my `ssh $HOST` solution

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me after finding `env -i` crashed subsequent program launches (because I guess they were looking for some of these vars):

```
foreach e (`env`)
    set name = `echo "$e" | cut -d "=" -f 1`
    if ("$name" != HOST || "$name" != "USER" || "$name" != "HOME" || "$name" != "SHELL" || "$name" != "PATH") then
        unsetenv "$name"
    endif
end
```